# Having trouble sending eth from Metamask

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to withdraw some eth from Metamask into my GDAX account.

I select the amount and add my GDAX eth address. I've tried using up to 25 gas.

After that nothing happens - it just shows the following:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong with the gas? Should I try using more?

Does the gas come from eth? I think I'm burning gas with all these attempts but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing and reinstalling metamask and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved the problem by removing Metamask from Chrome and installing it again. Now it works just fine.

Comment: That answer has already been given.